# CreateML DataFrame can't have column with element of unsupported type Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, createml

I'm following [Apple WWDC video here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10037/) about how to create a recommendation model. But I'm getting this error when I run the project on that like of code from their tutorial:

[image]

```
Column keywords has element of unsupported type Dictionary<String, Double>.
```

It seems like DataFrame doesn't support this type of data from the documentation here:

[image]

So am I missing something?